# internet explorer User-Agent header differs in HTTP call versus navigator.userAgent

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, http-headers, user-agent

I need to obtain the User-Agent header being used to send HTTP requests by AngularJS. When I use Internet Explorer, in Fiddler I see that the User-Agent being sent in requests is equal to this:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

However, when I obtain the user agent using `navigator.userAgent`, it returns this:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

I added the `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` tag in the HTML `<head>`, hoping that would resolve the issue, but it does not. I've also tried both enabling and disabling compatibility view for intranet (localhost, in this case) sites.

Background: the user-agent is being passed to a Windows click-once app via query string (along with an auth token in the query string). Windows app needs to use the same auth token and user agent as the AngularJS app, otherwise HTTP API calls result in a 401 if the user-agent differs. Windows app should not require user to sign in and should use same auth context as the browser user.

How can I obtain the actual User-Agent being sent that I am observing in Fiddler?

Comment: hi @kindohm, we got the same problems with our system... did you find solution for yours? appreciate if you share us... thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, the user agent string in Internet Explorer versions nine and higher, between the version send in the HTTP request and the one obtained via `navigator.userAgent` will almost ever differ because of the so called feature tokens in the string (only by chance on a fresh install they might bee for a short while the same). The background for this is explained here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

From the msdn-document:

> Earlier versions of Internet Explorer included feature tokens defined using the Pre-Platform and
>   Post-Platform keys part of the user-agent string during the HTTP negotiation process. Over time,
>   this lead to overly long user-agent strings, which in turn created problems for certain web servers.
>   Problems usually appeared when user-agent strings were longer than 256 characters. As of Internet
>   Explorer 9, the user-agent string no longer includes feature tokens during HTTP negotiation. Feature
>   tokens are included in the value returned by the userAgent property of the navigator object.
>   Applications that rely on the earlier behavior should be modified accordingly.

Setting the compatibility view mode with the `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />` meta tag has no influence on the user agent problem either (I've testes it in MSIE 10 and MSIE 11).

The only partitial solution I could imagine (which would be not reliable) would be to strip known feature properties from the string obtained via java script and try to compare the strings then.

Unfortunately I suspect you should try to find an other solution for your problem not involving the comparison of the user agent strings.

Comment: thanks. we're considering alternatives where we can avoid this check.